# How can I prove the maximum of the function $\frac{p(n)}{n}$ where $p(n)$ is the $n$th pisano period?

Tags: number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

I was recently watching a video on applications of the Fibonacci sequence in music, and came across the idea of pisano periods. For some number $n$, the pisano period is the period with which the sequence of Fibonacci numbers taken modulo $n$ repeats. While these numbers seem to grow with $n$, I was curious what would happen if you divided the pisano period by its own modulous.

$$
f(n) = \frac{p(n)}{n}
$$

I wrote some code to do this, but it seems like the above function maxes out at 6. For reference:

$$
\begin{align}
f(2) = 1.5 \\
f(3) = 2.6 \\
f(5) = 4 \\
f(6) = 4 \\
f(10) = 6 \\
f(50) = 6 \\
f(250) = 6 \\
f(1250) = 6 \\
\dots \\
f(781250) = 6
\end{align}
$$

Is there some way to prove the maximum of this function? Is it 6?

Comment: If I remember right the wikipedia article , $6n$ is in fact the maximum possible period.

Comment: Maybe , it is better to use $p(n)$ for the period to avoid confusion with the prime counting function $\pi(n)$

Comment: @peter yeah, it could avoid some confusion. I used $\pi(n)$ because that's what the Wikipedia article used, but I'm happy to change it.

Comment: Although not really a problem , I am a little surprised that wikipedia did not use $p(n)$. But as long as it is clarified what it means , everything is fine.

Answer (score -1):

On the [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A001175), one sees that K. S. Brown showed this. Here is the linked [pdf](https://oeis.org/A001175/a001175_1.pdf) on OEIS related to this fact.